# Showing object information in JSP page

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do an web application with Spring MVC and I have a difficult when I try to fill the JSP page with object information:

I have a class Pessoa ("Person"):

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPessoa;
    private String nome;
    private int rg;
    private TipoEstado rgEstado;
    private int cpf;
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Calendar dataNascimento;
    private String profissao;
    private String nomePai;
    private String nomeMae;
    private TipoEstadoCivil estadoCivil; //enum
    private TipoSituacao situacao; 

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idEndereco")
    private Endereco endereco;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", targetEntity = ContaCorretora.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ContaCorretora> contaCorretora;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", targetEntity = Telefone.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Telefone> telefone;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idContaBancaria")
    private ContaBancaria contaBancaria;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="email")
    private Usuario usuario;
```

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/listarPessoa/{id}") 
public ModelAndView listarPessoa(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pessoa/listaespecifica");
    Pessoa pessoa = pessoaDao.find(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("pessoa",pessoa);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

PessoaDAO method:

```
public Pessoa find(int id) {        
    return manager.createQuery("select p from Pessoa as p where p.idPessoa = :id", Pessoa.class)
            .setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
}
```

The main problem is that I can't show in the .JSP page the informations when the attribut has a relationship. When I put attributes without relationship, it works fine!

For instance:

This code above works:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>RG</b></td>
    <td>${pessoa.rg }</td>
</tr>
```

When I put the code like this, doesn't work: ("Endereco" is like "address", in this case is a OnetoOne relationship with pessoa, "logradouro" is an attribute of Endereco". Then, this code above doesn't work:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Endereco</b></td>
    <td>${pessoa.endereco.logradouro }</td>
</tr>
```

This is the error:

```
**type Exception report
message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/pessoa/listaespecifica.jsp at line 69
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/pessoa/listaespecifica.jsp at line 69
66:     </tr>
67:     <tr>
68:             <td><b>Endereco</b></td>
69:             <td>${pessoa.endereco.logradouro }</td>
70: 
71: 
72:     </tr>**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the fetch type of Endereco endereco to eager. Like this

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="idEndereco")
private Endereco endereco;
```